# List All Users That Have Retweeted A Tweet

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have recently put out a tweet on my twitter account, and it was quickly retweeted well over 100 times. Now the counter on the page of my tweet says 100+ retweets, but the actual number of retweets is much much higher.

Now I need to get a list with all Twitter user ids that have retweeted my tweet.

I get about 15 users on the actual page of the tweet, but the remaining users do not show up.

Is there a way for me to get the twitter user ids of all users that have retweeted my tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this method can help:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets_of_me Make sure to set `count=100` and iterate through all `pages` But i am not sure if it will give you all your unique tweets or all instances of retweeting.

Sure way to find them all is by searching: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search either look for your '@screen_name' or 'chunk of your tweet'